# JPA Hibernate: MetaModel is not generating correctly in embeddable class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, metamodel

I have the following entities

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddableEntity
{
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_entity_A")
    private EntityA entityA;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_entity_a")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", length = 50)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public abstract class EntityA
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    protected Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "embeddableEntity.entityA", orphanRemoval = true)
    protected EntityB entityB;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "boolean_field", columnDefinition = "TINYINT DEFAULT 0", nullable = false)
    private Boolean booleanField = false;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_entity_b")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", length = 50)
@DiscriminatorValue("entityb")
public class EntityB
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private EmbeddableEntity embeddableEntity;
}
```

I want JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor to generate a MetaModel class like this:

```
package br.com.loopec.loopkey.server.corp.persistence.entity;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(EmbeddableEntity.class)
public abstract class EmbeddableEntity_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<EmbeddableEntity, EntityB> entityB;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<EmbeddableEntity, Boolean> booleanField;

    public static final String ENTITY_B = "entityB";
    public static final String BOOLEAN_FIELD = "booleanField";
}
```

But all it generates for me is a class like this, omitting the entityB field I want generated:

```
package br.com.loopec.loopkey.server.corp.persistence.entity;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(EmbeddableEntity.class)
public abstract class EmbeddableEntity_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<EmbeddableEntity, Boolean> booleanField;

    public static final String BOOLEAN_FIELD = "booleanField";
}
```

I don't know it's useful information, but I've been facing this problem building the project from Docker.
My version of hibernate is: 5.4.15.Final
Can you see if I did something wrong with my code? I don't know if it's a hibernate bug, but I found a thread on stack overflow with another developer having a similar problem. [JPA Hibernate 5: OneToOne in nested Embeddable causes metamodel issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710730/jpa-hibernate-5-onetoone-in-nested-embeddable-causes-metamodel-issue)